# OOP PHP - Exposing Public Fields vs Using Public Accessors?

Tags: php, oop

Im just starting to learn PHP OOP - i have been using procedural style programming and stuck with it now I'm trying to get my head around using OOP - Whats the advantage to using public to private?

So

```
class person {
    public $name;
    function __construct($name) {
        $this->name = $name;
    }
}    

$newPerson = new person('Tom');
echo $newPerson->name;
```

VS

```
class person {
    private $name;
    function __construct($name) {
        $this->name = $name;
    }
    function getName() {
        return $this->name;
    }
}    

$newPerson = new person('Tom');
echo $newPerson->getName();
```

Whats the advantage to using the private vs public?

Comment: Private property is accessible only within class while you can access public property in the class and also in the child class.

Comment: @Deep Not really...

- *public* : Access from everywhere.
- *protected*: Access from the class and it's childrens.
- *private* : Access only from the class.

Comment: A good article for PHP http://russellscottwalker.blogspot.com/2013/09/public-properties-getters-and-setters.html. Overall though this is a pattern chose to use it or not. You will find evangelist and nay-sayers everywhere.

Answer (score -1):

In your case study both approachs are the same.

But the first approach doesn't really take benefits from OOP.
The second approach let's you extending the person class to redefine the getName function, like this :

```
class superPerson extends person {
     function getName() {
         return "Super " . parent::getName();
     }
}

$newPerson = new superPerson('Tom');
echo $newPerson->getName(); //Give you "Super Tom"
```